# How to concat socket response in an array?

Tags: typescript, websocket, concatenation

I have a socket that returns to me this:

Individual updates sample (blue line):

```
{
  "listBeans": [
    {
      "fruit": {
        "value": "apple"
      },
      "currentQuantity": {
        "value": "1"
      },
      "type": {
        "value": "B"
      },
      "price": {
        "value": "3.1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

History sample (red line):

```
{
  "listBeans": [
    {
      "fruit": {
        "value": "apple"
      },
      "currentQuantity": {
        "value": "1"
      },
      "type": {
        "value": "A"
      },
      "price": {
        "value": "3.1"
      }
    },
    {
      "fruit": {
        "value": "banana"
      },
      "currentQuantity": {
        "value": "4"
      },
      "type": {
        "value": "A"
      },
      "price": {
        "value": "7.1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to check if one of those return of socket already exists in my list, if they exists, I want to changes values from those, if not, I want 
 concat in my list

Facts: The first response of my socket always will be the history of the fruits, after that the next responses will be the updates of fruits.

the red line means the history, and the blue lines means the individual updates
[image: socket]

its not possible to diferrence if is an update or a history

first red line: history of type A

second red line: history of type B

This is what I got soo far:

```js
if (response['listBeans'].length > 1) { // only works if my history returns more than one 
  this.myList = 
  this.myList.concat(this.wsFormatter.formatResponse(response['listBeans'])); // will just format my response
  this.myList = this.myList.filter(f => f.currentQuantity !== '0'); // i want to display only fruits with quantity bigger than 1
  this.myList = this.formatList(this.myList); // this function is important, they will add some keys to my object via Rest API, this function only need to be called when is a new fruit in my list
} else {
for (const item of this.listPositions) {
    if (response['listBeans'][0].fruit.value === item.fruit) { // here i verify i the response is the same as my list
        item.price = response['listBeans'][0].price.value; // change the value of price in my list
        item.currentQuantity = response['listBeans'][0].currentQuantity.value; // change the value of currentQuantity in my list
     }
   }
 }
```

how i concat the new responses in my list (array)? my code only works if my historyis bigger than one, if my history response is one, my code dont work

This is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find if the item already exists in `history`. If exists, then update the item, else append the item.

```js
let history = { "listBeans": [{ "fruit": { "value": "apple" }, "currentQuantity": { "value": "1" }, "type": { "value": "A" }, "price": { "value": "3.1" } }, { "fruit": { "value": "banana" }, "currentQuantity": { "value": "4" }, "type": { "value": "A" }, "price": { "value": "7.1" } } ] };

let update = { "listBeans": [{ "fruit": { "value": "apple" }, "currentQuantity": { "value": "1" }, "type": { "value": "B" }, "price": { "value": "3.1" } }] };

function updateData(history, update) {
  update.listBeans.forEach(obj => {
    let index = history.listBeans.findIndex(item => item.fruit.value === obj.fruit.value);

    // Update item if already exists.
    if (index != -1) {
      history.listBeans[index] = { ...obj };
    } else {
      // Append item.
      history.listBeans.push({ ...obj });
    }
  });

  return history;
}

console.log(updateData(history, update));
```

> It is not possible to diferrence if is an update or a history.

In such case, assuming you have a global variable `history`, you can do something as shown below. Make sure to initialize `history` to an empty array.

```
// Incoming socket data.
let current = response; 

// Update history.
this.history = updateData(this.history, current);
```

Comment: @Igor - Check out my edited answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: hmm, this sample does not work, i got your logic, i will adapt here with your logic thx

Comment: @Igor - You can see it is working. You can also update input data and verify. You're welcome. If you think this answer has helped you, consider upvoting and marking it as accepted.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions @Igor.

Comment: hey, sorry for the late response, i soo busy with this project,
my final solution for this:

Comment: ```typescript

          response.forEach((value: any) => {
            const fruits = this.listPositions.filter(listPositions => fruits['fruit'] === value['fruit']);
            if (fruits[0]) {
              fruits[0].lastTrade = response[0].price;
              fruits[0].currentQuantity = response[0].currentQuantity;
            } else {
              this.myList.push(value);
              this.myList = this.formatAllPositions(this.myList);
            }
          });

```